# GCP Failure binding role cloudsql client to a SA through Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-sql, roles, service-accounts

When trying to bind cloudsql client role to a SA in GCP with Terraform next error is produce:

> Error setting IAM policy for service account '{}': googleapi: Error 400: Role roles/cloudsql.client is not supported for this resource., badRequest

This is my terraform code on file main.tf:

```
resource "google_service_account" "default" {
  account_id = var.service_account_name
  display_name = "ECB API Caller Cloud Function SA"
}

data "google_iam_policy" "default" {
  binding {
    members = ["serviceAccount:${google_service_account.default.email}"]
    role    = "roles/cloudsql.client"
  }
}

resource "google_service_account_iam_policy" "default" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.default.name
  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.default.policy_data
}
```

**Edit: Sorted**

After further investigation I found out a way. Not completely sure why, but as far as I am able to understand, you cannot allocate this role to the user but the other way around.

Whatever, this code snippet does the trick:

```
resource "google_service_account" "default" {
  account_id = var.service_account_name
  display_name = "ECB API Caller Cloud Function SA"
}

resource "google_project_iam_binding" "project" {
  project = var.project_id
  role    = "roles/cloudsql.client"

  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.default.email}",
  ]
```

Comment: I don't use Terraform but the error `service account '{}'` suggests that the value is unset (`{}`). The reference `google_service_account.default` appears to expect an `email` property but it appears to only have `account_id` and `display_name`. Do you need to set the `email` property? Or is there some mechanism whereby the value is computed (it would need the `account_id` and the Service Account's Project ID)?

Comment: Your first example is using a service account as a **resource**. Service accounts do not provide Cloud SQL features, therefore you cannot modify the service account's IAM policy with those permissions. The correct IAM policy to modify is the **project's**.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is a pretty finicky one but I think the solution here is to use `google_sql_user` for service accounts (with `type` `"CLOUD_IAM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT"`) as on this page:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_user